# Why is there no Subscribe overload which only takes an error handler?

Tags: c#, exception, system.reactive

IObservable has Subscribe overloads for Next, Next+Error, Next+Complete, Next+Complete+Error, but why is there no observable for just Errors alone?

I assume it's because there might be an IObservable of Exception's and it would cause conflicts, i.e.:

```
IObservable<Exception> obs;
obs.Subscribe(ex => { });
```

RX wouldn't know if you were subscribing to Next or Error.

Is there a way of subscribing to errors alone without creating an empty Complete delegate?

```
obs.Subscribe(
    o => { },
    ex =>
    {
        // error-handling-code
    });
```

Comment: Based on your related question, it sounds like you want to observe a stream of exceptions, but OnError is guaranteed to only ever give you one ... As Nenad has said.  Plus you've already come close ... You needan IObservable<Exception>, or Subject<Exception>, and to use OnNext, not OnError.  OnError would be for when your IObservable<Exception> hs an exception, not the stream itself.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, this seems to be intellectual question, so:

From c# compiler perspective, for IObservable method signature(s), what you're proposing would be (considering that T = Exception):

```
public static IDisposable Subscribe<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Action<T> onNext);
public static IDisposable Subscribe<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Action<T> onError);
```

Both methods overloads would have same signatures and it's not supported by the compiler.

From interfaces perspective, you have IObserver defined like this:

```
public interface IObserver<in T>
{
    void OnCompleted();
    void OnError(Exception error);
    void OnNext(T value);
}
```

Implementor of the interface has to be like this:

```
public class Observer<T> : IObserver<T>
{
    public void OnCompleted()
    {
    }

    public void OnError(Exception error)
    {
        // Do something with exception
    }

    public void OnNext(T value)
    {
    }
}
```

So, even if you don't specify OnNext = () => {}, underlying infrastructure has to implement it. You don't loose any performance specifying it.

From logical perspective of observer pattern, your intention is to subscribe asynchronously to the sequence of elements/events. Method signatures that omit OnNext function and leave only OnError would be misleading for users of Rx library. It's more clear if you explicitly state your intention that you don't want to do anything OnNext.

> Once the OnCompleted or OnError method has been received, the Rx
>   grammar guarantees that **the subscription can be considered to be
>   finished.**

What you're trying to do would be equivalent of making empty foreach loop and waiting for exception:

```
try
{
    foreach (var e in sequence)
    {
        // do nothing
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Do something
}
```

which is not common scenario.

Comment: This helps a lot thanks. Given that the whole point of IObservable is to receive a stream of objects it really does make sense that you would have to explicitly specify that you wish to do *nothing* when receiving those objects. In my code, I of course will be handling the OnNext calls, I just want to handle the exceptions separately, in another area of my code, where I will pull together multiple potential exception sources and probably use Amb to take the first to arrive. I am however wondering now if an IObservable<Exception> will make more sense for this particular use case.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you overlook:

> Once the `OnCompleted` or `OnError` method has been received, the Rx
>   grammar guarantees that the **subscription can be considered to be
>   finished**.

1. If you care just about exception that will terminate operation
   try-catch is what you need.
2. If you care about sequence of exceptions, you'll have to catch them and
   return using `observer.OnNext(ex)`, not to break subscription with `observer.OnError`.

Comment: No I haven't overlooked that, and I don't think it's even relevant. And no, a try catch will not help at all.

Comment: With observable you subscribe to sequence asynchronously. In your example you don't care about sequence at all. Just about 1 exception. Do you have any valid reason for using observable there?